# Use QtConcurrent::run with move only argument in c++11 mode

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I want to pass move only type (`std::unique_ptr` just for the most short example),
to function that I want to execute inside Qt thread pool,
but such code give compile time error:

```
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <memory>

void f(std::unique_ptr<int>)
{
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> p{new int{5}};
    QtConcurrent::run(f, std::move(p));
}
```

the compiler complains that such function (part of Qt `QtConcurrent/qtconcurrentrun.h`):

```
template <typename T, typename Param1, typename Arg1>
QFuture<T> run(T (*functionPointer)(Param1), const Arg1 &arg1)
{
    return (new StoredFunctorCall1<T, T (*)(Param1), Arg1>(functionPointer, arg1))->start();
}
```

requires `std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [с _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]` in other words it use copy instead of move.

I use C++11 only, for other Qt function that accepts `Function`, like `QObject::connect` I use `std::bind` trick:

```
std::bind([](const std::unique_ptr<int> &arg) {}, std::move(param));
```

but for some reason such code also doesn't compile:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> p{new int{5}};
auto func = std::bind([](std::unique_ptr<int>& a) {
        //call f here
    }, std::move(p));
QtConcurrent::run(func);
```

also complains about delete copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr`.

I can solve it of course with `std::shared_ptr/QSharedPointer`,
but may be some one suggest way without extra memory allocation?

Comment: Try wrapping the call in a lambda, rather than using `std::bind`, e.g., `auto wrapper = [&p]() -> void { f(std::move(p)); };`.

Comment: @bnaecker Hm, so you suggest take reference to "stack" variable, and after exit from function use this reference to stack in another thread, is this undefined behaviour?

Comment: In the example here, the function is called, runs, and returns before `main()` ends, so there's no dangling pointer. If you do want to keep the function and pointer around after the current scope ends, you'll of course need to keep the object on the heap, regardless of whether you use a lambda or `std::bind`.

Answer (score 2):

The long and the short of it is that, unfortunately, QtConcurrent does not support move semantics yet.

The primary workaround would be to do what `std::auto_ptr` did: move on copy in a wrapper. Tough but there's no other way until the move support gets added to Qt concurrent. It's not some extraordinarily hard thing to patch in, though.

Comment: Can you please add the version you are talking about?